# How to explain to a non-tech person that YouTube is not a CDN

Tags: youtube, video, streaming

We need to be able to stream a variety of video formats using http/https URLs that return the video, 24/7. The streams will be played in a variety of webplayers we know nothing about.

A non-technical colleague is asking me **why don't we simply use the uploaded movie in YouTube and just stream it from there, real time?** Purpose being to increase YouTube view count by our streaming. He said others are doing it.

I told him YouTube tries to protect itself from us downloading the movie, so we can't have stable URLs returning the media file. Not to mention it's not providing all the formats we need. He replied he has a YouTube downloader which never fails, so why can't we do the same.

**How can I easily explain in common terms YouTube is not a free video content delivery network and that view count can not be increased even if we could stream the media file from there?**

Comment: Maybe also remind him that section 5 of the YouTube EULA states that downloader programs are not allowed, and videos can only be viewed through a YouTube player

Answer (score 1):

YouTube only considers things as view if they can verify that there is a human wanting to watch a video and then actually doing it. This means that

- if someone clicks on your video and immediately leaves because it isn't what they expected,
- if a bot permanently "watches" a video or a series of videos on a loop,
- if a human gets paid to watch a video, and
- if a video is embedded and set to autoplay

it doesn't count as view as per YouTube's definition of the term "view".

YouTube further probably doesn't use just the download statistics for the file(s) they're offering, they use most likely the Google Analytics script they have on each normal video page and embed. If so, just using the direct link simply isn't detected by YouTube's normal statistics.

But what I think is the most compelling argument (as already mentioned in the comments): YouTube has terms which prohibit playback outside the normal embeds (and downloading), and which also prohibit the usage of bots to increase views.
If you're downloading stuff privately, nobody cares, but if you are a company boosting views to look better, you may end up getting the company channel terminated for violating the terms of service, at which point the company is banned from owning, accessing or operating a YouTube channel ever again.